# Auto open app from another app using android kotlin

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to open one/multiple app from another app automatically in a specific time.

I tried below code to open a specific app. But it is not working.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val openTimeMillis =
            System.currentTimeMillis() + (6 * 1000)  milliseconds
        scheduleAppOpenAndClose(this, openTimeMillis)
    }

    fun scheduleAppOpenAndClose(context: Context, openTimeMillis: Long) {
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

        val openIntent = Intent(context, AppOpenReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingOpenIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            openIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
        )
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, openTimeMillis, pendingOpenIntent)
    }
}
```

**AppOpenReceiver.kt**

```
class AppOpenReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        val launchIntent = context!!.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome") // Replace with your app's package name
        launchIntent?.let {
            it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            context.startActivity(it)
        }
    }
}
```

I was expecting to open chrome app after 6 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the receiver in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name="YourReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
    </receiver>
```

Like this